# Redirect miodominio.IT (without SSL) to https://www.miodominio.COM

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

We have 2 domanins: miodominio.it (**without** an SSL certificate) and miodominio.com (**with** SSL certificate)

Now the domain ".it" should redirect to the domain ".com" so that for every request as:

- miodomio.**it**
- www.miodominio.**it**
- http**s**://miodominio.**it**
- http**s**://www.miodominio.**it**

it's always redirected to https://www.miodominio.**COM**

Actually if I type in the browser:

**www**.miodominio.**it** it correctly redirects me to https://www.miodominio.**COM**

meanwhile if I type:

miodominio.**it** (**without www**) it redirects me to http**s**://miodominio.**IT** (instead of the .com) but in this case I have a warning message because the domain **.IT** do not have an SSL certificate, and also it's not redirected to the .com.

How could I solve it so that whatever I have before .miodominio.IT it's always correctly redirected to https://www.miodominio.com ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SSL Cert warning cannot be avoided using rewrite rules as cert exchange happens well before mod_rewrite is even invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} miodominio\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.miodominio.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Croises, thanks so much for your solution. It worked fine for the simple domain redirect. However Google indexed yet some pages as miodominio.IT /something /something , so I would redirect also those links to miodominio.COM /something /something. Actually your rules do not redirects also those URLs. Any solution?

Comment: Yes, my code also redirects all links with pages ! (it's the `%{REQUEST_URI}` part)

Comment: Hi Croises, the problem is that in my case it redirects correctly only the homepage and not other links. I don't know why...

Comment: There must be another configuration problem, because with my code the entire uri is retained